# MacBook Pro battery question

Tags: macbook, battery, charging

I just got a new battery for my MacBook Pro...charged it for 2 days, but the battery icon has an x in the middle. Also the charge LED never goes green, stays on orange.

Comment: Question is ... ?

Comment: @Sathya I assume it's "What's going on? Why is it misbehaving like this? How do I fix it?". I almost added something like that when I fixed up his post a bit, but I didn't want my edit to be too invasive.

Answer (score 2):

Try [resetting your MacBook Pro's System Management Controller (SMC)](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964). The SMC controls power management functions like battery charging, and if it gets into a bad state, it might not charge a battery correctly.

If that doesn't fix it, call support or take it back to the store. Sounds like a bad battery that shouldn't have made it out of the factory.